# Can't figure out how to type this sum in python

Tags: python

This sum keeps giving me he wrong answer.
We were told to give variables values and workout sums and one of them is A×B÷(C×D)
The right answer is 0.0625 and it keeps coming out as 16.
I am just wondering why this is happening and what I am doing wrong.

This is what I wrote in python maybe someone can tell me what I am missing.

```
print(int(A*B/C*D))


A = 2
B = 4
C = 8
D = 16
```

I am also confused with this one A^((B + C) × D)
this is how I wrote it in python 
    (A**(B+C)*D))

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your formula is AXB÷(CXD), you should have typed it as `A*B/(C*D)`...

Comment: presume it's an order of operations problem, try adding the brackets in to the python version as per the question

Comment: And assign the variables before calculating the expression.

Comment: Also using `print(int(...` will make it display 0, and if you're in python 2 one of the numbers need to be a float.

Comment: print(int(A*B/(C*D))) This isn't working either.

Comment: Yes Parchment it is now showing 0

Comment: I think you should have written `print(A*B/float(C*D))`. The `float` is there to prevent the automatic conversion to integer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Parchment that seems to have done the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Because * and / have the same precedence. Your formula is interpreted as (((A*B)/C)*D)

Also you should convert your operands to float otherwise you will only get 0 as result.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your parentheses are wrong, but that's already been cleared up.

Secondly, I assume you are using Python 2.x, in which integer division returns integers: 1/2 == 0. To fix this, make the numbers floats: A = 2.0; B = 4.0; …

Or use Python 3.x.

Comment: Or `from __future__ import division` as the first line of your program in python 2.x

Answer (score 0):

As some people said above, your formula is wrong, which should be (A*B) / (C*D) or A*B / (C*D)  withouth int()

Since you have int() to convert the final result, you will never have float number, if the outcome of operation is from 0 to 1(exclusive), int(outcome) is always 0.

In python2.x, at least one of operands should be float to output float result.
In python3.x, the python interpreter will automatically convert your result to float if needed.